# Can you not spend any talent points in hard mode?

Tags: the-witcher-2

My brother and I recently beat our copies of The Witcher 2, and, being the masochists we are, both decided to up the difficulty and play the other story branch.

He finished before me, and experienced an irritating bug where he was not able to spend talent points after leveling up, and when I started over on hard a day later, I had experienced the same "bug".

Given that it's unlikely for such an egregious bug to happen in exactly the same way on two separate computers, etc., we were wondering if this was because of our choice in difficulty; can you not spend talents on Hard mode? I mean, I know it's supposed to be *harder*, but no talents *at all?*.

Comment: You have to spend 6 talents in the main Witcher Training tree before unlocking the other paths. Have you done that yet?

Comment: @Spugsley - I can't spend any talents in the *Training* tree.

Comment: Are you in meditation mode?

Comment: @Stecya - Should I be? I always added my abilities via hitting 'c'.

Comment: I also have this bug? on Insane and Hard mode. I'm hoping this isn't a design choice. The manual makes no mention of this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that in order to increase the difficulty, the Hard and Insane difficulties prevent you from spending talent points outside of meditation, in order to prevent you from upgrading your character mid-battle to survive.

To upgrade your abilities on Hard and Insane, meditate, then select the Character option. Here, you can assign talent points.

Comment: That doesn't make the game *harder*, it just makes the already poor interface more of a hassle... :/

Comment: But it makes it closer to a real-life experience, what the difficulty settings suggest.

Comment: @Bora Yes, because when I want to learn some complicated new sword technique, I can't just do instantly.  I have to meditate for an hour.

Comment: @bwarner Oh man, I thought I was the only one who did that!

Comment: Wasn't it always like this?  I can't say that I've played Witcher 2 yet but this was always the case in the first game but on normal difficulty.  As far as I knew, you _had_ to meditate in order to spend your talents.

Comment: @Jeff, not really. On easy and normal, you just press C to enter character screen and upgrade. In fact, I did this in the middle of a fight during the Prologue :)

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the answer. I was finding this annoying.